# Slick update field in entity after filter but before update/exclude field from update?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

In the following function, I'm updating a user. But the user has a 'createdDate' field that will be in the db, but won't be in the user entity passed by the client:

```
def update(user: User): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(
      userTable
        .filter(_.userId === user.userId)
        // Can I set user.createdDate here to the existing value?
        .update(user)
    )
}
```

Is it possibly to set user.createdDate, using the value from the existing user row in the db before I call update(user)?

For reference here is how I set the createdDate field when creating a user (User is an immutable case class, so I do a copy to set the createdDate):

```
def create(user: User): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(userTable += user.copy(
      createdDate = Option(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()))))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just doing a read before update, like this:

```
this.read(user.userId).flatMap {
    case Some(existingUser) =>
        db.run(
            userTable.
            filter(_.userId === user.userId).
            update(user.copy(createdDate = existingUser.createdDate)))
    case None => throw new NotFoundException(...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can destructure the user object like this and skip `createdDate`.

```
userTable
  .filter(_.id === id)
  .map(t => (t.firstName,..., t.modifiedDate))
  .update(("John",..., Some(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now))))
```

Comment: Thanks, though my User class has lots of fields, about 15 (not shown in my example), so this might be a bit unwieldy with lots of fields? Also, what if a field was added to User at a later date - you'd have to know to update this method with the new field?

Comment: You can define that `updateFunction` inside `map` within the User case class or its companion. Perhaps that helps keeping them together.